# Erroneous Output for Path Check in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, file, if-statement, pathlib

I was just experimenting with the `pathlib` library in **`Python 3.6`**. I wanted to check if such a file with the given file name exists in the path that I have given. Here is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path
f = Path('/Libraries/Documents/sample.txt')
print("File {} Exists".format(f)) if f.exists() else print("False")
```

And the output that I got was:

```
>>> False
```

while such a file truly existed in that path.

What could be the possible error in the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works well when I made a small modification to the above code.

```
import pathlib
f = pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\user\Documents\sample.txt')
print("File {} Exists".format(f)) if f.exists() else print("False")
```

And I got the correct output this time

```
>>> File C:\Users\user\Documents\sample.txt Exists
```

I figured out that I got erroneous output previously because I had missed that r in path specification